# How do I prepare a system for minimum possible damage in the case of a crash or hard reboot?

Tags: linux, filesystems, crash, reboot

Assume you are testing something that you know may result in a system crash (perhaps since you observed it before). A system crash may lead to inconsistent file systems and other nasty consequences.

What steps should be taken to minimize any possible damage? I would imagine it to be wise to have a backup of all important data, to terminate all unnecessary processes and to sync the hard disks before the critical operation - but perhaps there is a more structured and/or standardized approach? Are there perhaps ways to prevent writing to the hard disk for a certain amount of time (and is this commonly used in this context)? Does it actually make a difference if hard disks were sync'ed?

I am primarily interested in Linux systems (with xfs file system) but I ask this as a general (OS independent) question as I am asking for a general, structured, standardized approach.

Similar questions:

- [This question](https://superuser.com/q/1081971/164391) touches a little bit on what I am asking but focuses on power surge damage as does the answer.
- [This unix.stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305860/199642) asks for general advice on the design of a system that will be prone to power outages and crashes. The answer focuses on file system choice and options and suggests full data journaling to prevent data loss.